# Sorcery Rails Authentication Submodules Not Loading Properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I am using Sorcery version 0.11.0 for Rails authentication.
Rails verison 5.1.4, Ruby version 2.4.2

If I start a bare app (with the same versions of Ruby, Rails and Sorcery), using the default User class, there is no problem.

In my real app, when I include a submodule, the instance and class methods are not being added, and I cannot figure out why.

I am using a Person class as the authenticated class.

My `config/initializers/sorcery.b` file has this at the top:

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.submodules = [:reset_password, :remember_me]
```

And this at the bottom (before the last `end`):

config.user_class = "Person"

With that config, I believe that an instance of the Person class should respond to `remember_me!` and `deliver_reset_password_instructions!` (among others) and these should show up when I do `person.methods` in the console. They show up in my small test app but not in my real app.

In the console, if I do:

```
Sorcery::Controller::Config.user_class
```

it returns

```
"Person"
```

Authentication in general otherwise works fine. It's just the submodules I'm having a problem with.

I've used sorcery with submodules in several projects and have never had this issue.

Is there anything else I might be missing that I should look for?